# Rails Model: How to make an attribute protected once it's created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was just wondering: How can i make an attribute "write once" ?
To be more precise, I'm using Devise and I want the user to be able to register with this email but then, once it's done, I want this email locked.

I read that forms can easily be bypass, so I want to make sure my model does that.

Also, i'm using in one of my form that: `<%= f.email_field :email, :id => "email", :disabled => "disabled" %>`

Is there any risks that an user can modify his email after being registered?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr_readonly` allows setting a value at creation time, then prevents modifying it on updates.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_readonly :email

end
```

Comment: If i do that, an user can't create his account. I need to be able to write once, then put it in read only. Something like `after_create`, change its property...

Comment: I've read your updates. It seems that Devise doesn't like that i change the email to `attr_readonly` On the signup page, i get the error "email can't be blank".

Comment: Anyway, it seems that my problem is a different question. Thanks for your help, I'll search a bit before asking another question about my bug with Devise.

Comment: You mean it says `email can't be blank` even though you entered an email address?  Or do you mean you don't want the email address to be required during sign-up?

Comment: I mean i have this message even though I entered an email address :(